# Run ReSharper plugin tests using R# test runner

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, resharper-plugins

I'm building a R# plugin and decided to cover it with tests. However, I noticed, that plugin tests cannot be run using the R# runner if plugin target version is the same as R# version.

For instance, if you try to run tests using `JetBrains.ReSharper.SDK.Tests` of version `2016.2.20160818.171542`, you'll get the following error:

`ERROR System.TypeLoadException: 
Method 'RunTests' in type 'JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit26.BuiltInNUnitRunner' from assembly 'JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.nUnit26, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.`

In previous versions the error was different.

Likely, that happens because R# runner and SDK assemblies make a mix.

Is there any way to configure project/R# to be able to run plugin unit tests using the R# runner? Likely, R# dev team uses their own runner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in the ReSharper runner in 201.6.2. Something to do with having multiple copies of the same assemblies in the same process - the assemblies from the install, and the assemblies from the bin folder. Something's getting messed up along the way.

You can subscribe to, vote and track this issue: [RSRP-460399](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-460399)

The workaround is to install an older version of ReSharper into a Visual Studio "experimental instance" aka "custom hive", and use this instance to develop and test the plugin. The normal instance can be used for other day-to-day development.

You can [download an older version of ReSharper here (e.g. 2016.1.2)](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207242355-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-), and in the installer, click Options and enter the name of a custom instance, e.g. "Plugins". Then create a new shortcut to Visual Studio and set the command line to "devenv.exe /rootSuffix Plugins" (or whatever you called the custom hive).

Answer (score 2):

R# and SDK must be either of different major versions, or of binary compatible versions. Unfortunately, within EAP the internal APIs inside the test runner have changed, so R# and SDK from different EAPs are not compatible.